# External Data Refresh Failed - which setting is causing this error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, excel-services

I'm getting this error message when trying to refresh a workbook.

The `odc` file is saved in the `Data Connections` library of the sub-site. The excel olap pivot report is saved in a document library of the same sub-site.

Which setting will I need to change?

[image]

If I manually uncheck the "Always use connection" setting as follows:

[image]

Then I still get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To work around this issue, follow these steps:

1. Open the workbook in an Excel client application.
2. Select the data connection that is listed in the error message, and
   then click Properties under the Data tab.
3. Clear the Always use connection file check box under the Definition
   tab.
4. Republish the workbook to the WAC server.

here is the KB for above: [2758432](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2758432)

also check this Technet for configuring it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525341(v=office.15).aspx#part4

Comment: +1 thanks for this information but when i do this I still get an error message: I will edit OP.

Comment: 2758432 is not correct in this context: SharePoint Server should support `odc` files that link through to Analysis Services cube.