# SharePoint 2013 Excel Services & External Data Refresh Failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, excel-services, data-connection

I need advice how I can fix problem with Excel external data connection.

I have an excel file, which have connection to SSAS. Excel file "refresh all" works fine if I download it out from SharePoint. However, if I try use file in excel services it gives me an error message: "External Data Refresh Failed".

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried various fixes, what I could find in google but no luck.
What I have tried:

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.fi/2013/09/external-data-refresh-failed-error.html

I have add libraries:

Manage Excel Services Application

- Trusted File Locations
- Trusted Data Connection Libraries

I tried with connection file and without.
[External Data Refresh Failed - which setting is causing this error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92882/external-data-refresh-failed-which-setting-is-causing-this-error)

So, what next? Any clues / tips, what I should try next? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select None instead of windows account if you have already configured unattended account into secure store

Comment: Did this work?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I have done the same thing, but I still get an error in the data model has anyone resolved this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

First, inspect the SharePoint ULS trace log for errors. Filter on the Excel Services category. If the error *pf_check_error 0x80070542* shows then you need to check the *Claims to Windows Token Service* in SharePoint. It must be started and it must also be running as Local System.

Use the */_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx* page in SharePoint Central Administration to check the service account. Alternatively, it can also be checked with PowerShell using these two commands:

```
$si = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'Claims to Windows Token Service' }
$si.Service.ProcessIdentity
```

If the identity is not *LocalSystem* then it must be reconfigured with the following PowerShell commands:

```
$si = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'Claims to Windows Token Service' }
$si.Service.ProcessIdentity.CurrentIdentityType=0
$si.Service.ProcessIdentity.Update()
$si.Service.ProcessIdentity.Deploy()
```